# Silverlight accessing Storyboard from another Class

Tags: silverlight, storyboard

I'm facing a problem that I probably can't solve on my own, I'm working on a solution now for 2 days and browsed a lot in other Forums etc. - but it seems like that I just don't get it.

**My problem**

I have a Storyboard called "getVisible" in my UserControl "MainPage" that I want to access in another class called "test.cs"

However, as the Storyboard is defined in the MainPage.xaml and only the App Resources are accessible, do I face the problem that I can't load Storyboards from another class.

Any ideas how to solve that?

~regards Matt

Answer (score 0):

One option to get the storyboard from test.cs is to create an instance of MainPage.

```
(new MainPage()).Resources["getVisible"];
```

Alternatively though, you may wish to consider creating the resources in a separate resource dictionary and then referencing that shared resource dictionary from both loactions.

Comment: Thanks for your response !

The written example of yours is one option I also thought about, but its more like that you're creating an instance of something that already exists.

Also strangely nothing happens when I'm starting the Storyboard from another class with `Storyboard b = (Storyboard)(new MainPage()).Resources["getVisible"];
b.Begin();`

Comment: What I forgot to mention is, when I'm placing the Storyboards into a shared source dictionary refuses Expression Blend to show the Storyboards in the StoryBoard List.